# SymmetricDS Pro trial version on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-synchronization, symmetricds

How can I install SymmetricDS Pro trial version on Ubuntu?
I have already tried to copy the web directory of the pro version into the directory of the community version. But some errors occur.

Answer (score 1):

The Professional installation comes with it's own installer.

To install with the gui execute the following.

```
java -jar symmetric-pro-x.x.xx-setup.jar
```

If you want to install headless execute the following...

```
java -jar symmetric-pro-3.5.11-setup.jar -console
```

You will want to install Pro in a new location.

1) Install Pro in a new location.

2) Shutdown your open source instance.

3) Copy your properties file from your open source engines folder to the Pro engines folder. This will preserve any of your old settings including the database you are syncing.

3) Run the Pro instance.